# How to use creation_time and forecast_time in google earth engine to get forecast data?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to get the forecast rainfall for let say three days after this day of writing using the data from Google Earth Engine's [NOAA GFS (Global Forecast System): 384-hour predicted atmosphere data](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/NOAA%2FGFS0P25). However, I am having a difficulty in utilizing the "creation_time" and "forecast_time" in the codes. I was told that this is different from the .filterDate command.

```js
//Load input imagery.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GFS0P25')
  .select("total_precipitation_surface")
  .filterDate("2018-02-15", "2018-02-19");

// Define a region of interest as a buffer around a point.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(124.265, 7.8675);

// Center map
Map.centerObject(geom, 14);

//Create time series and print the chart.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection, geom, ee.Reducer.mean(), 250));

//Create day of year (DOY) and print the chart.
print(ui.Chart.image.doySeries(collection, geom, ee.Reducer.mean(), 350));
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question adding your code at the moment or the question could be closed

Answer (score 2):

`creation_time` and `forecast_time` are dates in [epoch format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can use any date, *but!* you need to specify the hour and transform it.

From the link you posted:

> The 384-hour forecasts, with 3-hour forecast interval, are made at
>   6-hour temporal resolution (i.e. updated four times daily)

So, each forecast is distributed every 6 hours in 173 scenes. How to select a forecast set? Specify 'creation_time'. For example, *2018-02-15 06:00:00* forecast series:

```js
var collection = imageCollection
                 .select('precipitable_water_entire_atmosphere')       
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('creation_time',ee.Date(0).update(2018,2,15,6,0,0).millis()));
```

`ee.Date(0)` creates a date object (millisecond equal to 0) and `update(2018,2,15,6,0,0)` assing  custom date in `(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss)` format. Finally `.millis()` returns epoch time value (`'creation_time'` format). Result are 173 scenes (384-hour forecast, by 3 hours).

If you want to specify an specific forecast from the serie, use `'forecast_hours'` or `'forecast_time'`. For example:

```js
var collection = imageCollection
                 .select('precipitable_water_entire_atmosphere')       
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('creation_time',ee.Date(0).update(2018,2,15,6,0,0).millis()));
                 .filter(ee.Filter.eq('forecast_hours',72));
```

Return:

```json
{
  "type": "Image",
  "bands": [
    {
      "id": "precipitable_water_entire_atmosphere",
      "data_type": {
        "type": "PixelType",
        "precision": "double"
      },
      "dimensions": [
        1441,
        721
      ],
      "crs": "EPSG:4326",
      "crs_transform": [
        0.25,
        0,
        -180.125,
        0,
        -0.25,
        90.125
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 1518706616651754,
  "id": "NOAA/GFS0P25/2018021506F072",
  "properties": {
    "creation_time": 1518674400000,
    "system:time_start": 1518674400000,
    "forecast_time": 1518933600000,
    "system:footprint": {
      "type": "LinearRing",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          -180,
          -90
        ],
        [
          180,
          -90
        ],
        [
          180,
          90
        ],
        [
          -180,
          90
        ],
        [
          -180,
          -90
        ]
      ]
    },
    "forecast_hours": 72,
    "system:asset_size": 19864288,
    "system:index": "2018021506F072"
  }
}
```